# facebook javascript sdk UI dialog resetting scroll position

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have a long page, where near the bottom I have a "post on facebook" button.  when the user clicks this the FB.UI dialog from the facebook javascript sdk pops-up.  This is all working fine except that the page scrolls back to the top of the page where the dialog is showing.
i have the   set just under the  tag as facebook recommends. I've tried moving this to the part of the page where i need it but the page keeps scrolling back to the top

Any idea how i can get the facbook dialog to show where the current page scroll position is?

Comment: its maybe worth a try: FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,10000);

Comment: Set the position as fixed for the FB button or surround it in a div that's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `position:fixed;` attribute within the element that contains the Facebook dialogue. Check out this [link](http://hhttp://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for further information and examples.